# Generic Makefile not working on FreeBSD

Tags: makefile, freebsd, cc

Please note that this is not a duplicate of the other questions named generic makefile.

I have followed all of the instructions on other questions about generic makefiles, and this is the code I have come up with from that:

```
CFLAGS = -c
CC = cc
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cc)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,%(SOURCES))
EXEC = run

all: build clean

build: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC)

%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

clean:
    rm *.o
```

However, when I execute `make` with a file called `test.cc` in my directory, it gives me the followig error:

```
cc    -o run
cc: error: no input files
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /somewhere
```

Please note that I am on FreeBSD and the `make` and `cc` commands are the ones which come with the OS.

Comment: Note: If the *.cc files contain C++, you should use a C++ compiler. `CC = cc` is very likely a C compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lines

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cc)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,%(SOURCES))
```

are GNU make syntax, not understood by FreeBSD's `make`, which has its own dialect (specifically `$(wildcard)` and `$(patsubst)`). If you need to write makefiles portable to many systems, either require gmake to exist and use GNUmakefiles, or stick to the [features of POSIX make](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html).

You can install GNU make (`gmake`) on FreeBSD with

```
cd /usr/ports/devel/gmake
make install clean
```

Comment: What would be freebsd's version of these two lines?

Answer (score 4):

In FreeBSD's `make`, you can do it like this:

```
SOURCES!= ls *.cc
OBJECTS = ${SOURCES:.cc=.o}
```

The first line uses a *variable assignment modifier*. Expand the value and pass it to the shell for execution and assign the result to the variable. Any newlines in the result are replaced with spaces. This is a very powerfull mechanism. You should e.g. use `find` instead of `ls` to also search in subdirectories;

```
SOURCES!= find . -type f -name '*.cc'
```

The second line uses a *variable modifier* to perform AT&T System V UNIX style variable substitution. It replaces the suffix `.cc` with the `.o` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

`make` on FreeBSD is different from GMake (`make` command on most linux systems), and those features require GMake. Run the command `gmake` instead.

I am not familiar with exactly which features require GMake.