# GNU make wildcard alternative?

Tags: makefile, wildcard, freebsd

I would like to select all files in directory but using FreeBSD's make.

In GNU make this approach works:

```
FILES=$(wildcard *.c)
```

I am using FreeBSD's make, not GNU make so I am looking for command that will work in FreeBSD's make.

As it's stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263797/generic-makefile-not-working-on-freebsd), FreeBSD has its own functions but I cannot find them.

Comment: I don't really know bsd make but quick searching doesn't indicate anything being available for this specifically. The only thing I can see is the fact that targets and sources can contain shell wildcard characters (which is true in GNU make also).

Comment: If you want to find all information about FreeBSD's make, this can be found here in the man pages:
https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `!=` to execute a command in FreeBSD's `make`. E.g:

```
FILES!= ls *.c
```

or if you want to find files in subdirectories as well;

```
FILES!= find . -type f -name '*.c'
```

Comment: Great! Worked in FreeBSD 12.4