# How to specify in Makefile.am(auto make) for saving library object files(.lo) and object files(.o) in separate folder after compilation

Tags: c++, makefile, automake

In Makefile.am, I have:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmyproject.la
libmyproject_la_LDFLAGS = -shared
libmyproject_la_SOURCES = \
    sample1.cpp \
    sample1.h \
    sample2.cpp \
    sample2.h
AM_CPPFLAGS = \
    -Wall \
    -Wextra
INCLUDES = \
    $(OPENSSL_CFLAGS)
LIBS = \
    -L/usr/lib/openssl-1.0.0/ \
    -lssl
EXTRA_DIST = xxxxxx
```

This works fine and I'm getting `.lo` and `.o` files in the same path.

What can I do to have all `.lo` and `.o` files moved to a separate subfolder after compilation?

Comment: I never used automake before, but I have acompleshed this in [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974007/geting-source-code-structure-in-makefile), but with regular makefiles. I do not know if there is some difference with automake.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you can mix in ordinary `make` rules into your `Makefile.am`.

So adding the following to `Makefile.am` should do what you want:

```
.PHONY: copy_obj
# when building 'all', we *also* want the 'copy_obj' target
all: copy_obj
# but the 'copy_obj' target can only be executed once 'libmyproject.la' is done
copy_obj: libmyproject.la
      mkdir -p objdir
      cp *.lo *.o objdir
```

or even:

```
.PHONY: copy_obj

all: copy_obj
copy_obj: $(libmyproject_la_OBJECT)
      mkdir -p objdir
      cp $^ objdir
```

But the real question is: *why* would you actually want to do that? What do you try to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [VPATH](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/VPATH-Builds.html) build.  Having some insight as to why the `.lo` and `.o` files need to be elsewhere would help answer your question.

A somewhat different variation on this is the [DESTDIR](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/DESTDIR.html) install where the libs, etc. get copied and the `.o` files don't.